# Initializing SharedPreferences gives: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, null-pointer

When I launch my app it just crashes and gives me this error code.:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

This is my main activity:

```
package com.awplicity.testappshared;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.nextAct:
                editor.putString("mystring", "Hi");
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.awplicity.testappshared.Main2Activity"));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second activity:

```
package com.awplicity.testappshared;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_main2);
        setText();
    }

    public void setText() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        tv.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("mystring", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: To attract more attention to your questions, please make the titles more descriptive since that is all anyone can see when they go to this site

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally speaking, you cannot call methods that you inherit from `Activity` (or subclasses, like `AppCompatActivity`) until inside of the `onCreate()` method. Until then, things are not set up yet.

Hence, change:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

to:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

and initialize those fields in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}
```